# Images won't display through CSS

Tags: css, image

If I try to set a background image using CSS, it flat out will not load. If I use the same path in HTML, it will. I am making a slider of these images, hence I need it to work with CSS. I've browsed every answer on the internet to similar problems and nothing works.

Relevant HTML:

```
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="slider5"></div>
                    <div class="slider4"></div>
                    <div class="slider3"></div>
                    <div class="slider2"></div>
                    <div class="slider1"></div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-container {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}

```
.slider1, .slider2, .slider3, .slider4, .slider5 {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: static;
top: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0s linear;
-o-transition: all 0s linear;
```

}

```
.slider1 {
background: url(../images/jbscomicback.jpg) no-repeat;
display:block;
animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-o-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
```

}

^repeated for each .slider(number)

Comment: You probably have a relative path issue.  Check the network tab in the dev tools.

Comment: The relative url in CSS is relative to the location of the CSS file. In HTML, a relative url is relative to the location of the HTML file. Is your CSS file in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: My CSS is in a separate folder named "/assets/stylesheets", the images are in "/assets/images", and the HTML for the page in question is just in my main website folder. Dev tools and firebug both say it should work.

Comment: try setting the height where you have set it to auto.

Comment: Background images don't occupy space. You element needs a static  height property.

Comment: Setting the height worked as far as making the image appear, but now it no longer fits to different sized desktops and adds a black bar across the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height

Updated CSS

```
.slider-container {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: auto;}
.slider1, .slider2, .slider3, .slider4, .slider5 {
width: 100%;
height: 400px; /*------------Height-----------*/
position: static;
top: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0s linear;
-o-transition: all 0s linear;    }
.slider1{background:url(background: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat;) no-repeat;
display:block;
animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-o-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider-container">
                <div class="slider1"></div>
                <div class="slider1"></div>
                <div class="slider1"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Setting the height worked as far as making the image appear, but now it no longer fits to different sized desktops and adds a black bar across the bottom.

Comment: you need to use media screen to make it responsive. Not sure how you getting the black bar across the bottom as I have just added height in the CSS and also checked in my browsers. No such issues found.!

Comment: I figured out why there's a black bar: the third image is displaying underneath the other four despite the size and code being identical...

Comment: I don't find any such issue. I also put a margin-bottom:1px  to see if realy something odd there. But there was nothing. Set the margin-bottom 1px here **.slider1, .slider2, .slider3, .slider4, .slider5 ** and see if there any issue.

Comment: I set the margin and got no change.

Comment: The problem is that since I changed the height, <section> and <footer> are now moved to the top of the page, right under the navbar. If I change the height back to auto, they go back to where they should be.